# How can one apply padding from one text baseline to another?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

Say the code below is correct.  How can I apply a padding from the baseline of SubtitleText to the baseline of the Title Text?

```
            Column(...) {
               
                TitleText(...)

                SubTitleText(...)
                
            }
```

In a nutshell,How can I achieve this in Jetpack Compose?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can control padding in every direction independently in compose as below:

```
Text(text = "MyText"
     modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp,
                                 bottom = 16.dp,
                                 start = 0.dp,
                                 end = 0.dp))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @viv3k. I really appreciate it. 
Unfortunately, this does not give me the desired result.

However, what I do know is, Modifier.padding() is applied from the bounding box of the content. Which is not what I desire in this case. 
I know of Modifier.paddingfrombaseline() as well.

The result I desire is padding applied from the baseline of the subtitle text to the baseline of the title text.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting here. You have two boxes stacked on top of each other and you can control the padding and height of them, which can be manipulated to achieve the desired result.

Comment: If you want more granular control of how you arrange content, you can actually write ConstraintLayout in compose. Refer: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout